# How to render Blazor application to image file in background

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to build/compose an E-Ink display to render some temperature values from my smart home solution openHAB. The E-Ink display will be powered by a Raspberry Pi Pico. Rendering the temperatures shall happen in a Blazor application, running on a Raspberry Pi 4 in the background.

I found another project (ESPHome) which does the heavy lifting of rendering. All I need is an image file to render, i. e. the Blazor website needs to be rendered to a certain screen size and saved to a file.

So my question: how can I render a Blazor application to an image file in some kind of background service?

Thanks!

PS: I already found this https://github.com/tossnet/Blazor-Screenshot. However, it seems to me that this project requires an (inter)active browser session with user interaction.

Comment: "how can I render a Blazor application to an image file in some kind of background service?"  Blazor is the UI, building an image file in the background is a plain DotNetCore application.  What context you do that in depends on your application design.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how your comment is going to help me  if my question is not clear enough, please do not hesitate to tell me which kind of information you're missing. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to capture the rendered screen like in the link you provided, you can consider calling the JS method in [OnAfterRenderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.onafterrenderasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Ah does `OnAfterRenderAsync` also get called in headless mode, i. e. when there is no browser/renderer involved? That would be indeed easy...